# Like an article without a comment

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

I'm trying to setup "Like" button on productpages in our shop. I'm using iframe version of "like button" app. 
Unfortunatelly liked product is available on user's wall *only* when he add a comment additionally (liked page without a comment is invisible on his wall).

Code I have used:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.limango.pl%2Ffbfeed%3Fprodid%3D304983+&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=recommend&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

and the result page (with opengraph data) is located here: http://www.limango.pl/fbfeed/?prodid=313198

What mistake I made that I cannot post this without a comment?

Thanks in advance for any response.

Kind regards,
Slawek.

Answer (score 0):

Found in Google:

"The Like / Recommend button without comment – When third-parties use the standard iframe Like button with a width less than 400 pixels, the button_count, or  box_count version of the Like / Recommend button, users aren’t given the option to comment. A simple, one-line story linking to the content is published to the Recent Activity feed of the user’s wall, and the story is less frequently displayed in the news feeds of friends. Users are subscribed to future updates from the button’s owner."